# Consolidate Dynamic Range (Consolidate Function)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the Consolidate function of Excel to sum and consolidate the range below (see picture) .

[image]

The duplicates always occur in the 'Ref' column, and I want to sum the amount and consolidate like this:

[image]

The problem I have is that this range isn't always the same amount of rows.
What dynamic reference can I use instead of the R1C1:R14C6 range reference to achieve this?

```
Selection.Consolidate Sources:= _
    "'C:\Path\Path\Desktop\[TestBook.xlsm]Temp'!R1C1:R14C6", Function:=xlSum, _
    TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True
```

Comment: Look into `Range.Address()` you can denote Absolute,R1C1 and return the full external source.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comment I worked out the solution using Range.Address() :

```
Set dynamicRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Selection.Consolidate _
Sources:=dynamicRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True), _
Function:=xlSum, _
TopRow:=True, _
LeftColumn:=True, _
CreateLinks:=False
```